# Neo4j 2.2 import tool doesn't Ignore field as expected

Tags: import, neo4j

The documentation (http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/import-tool-header-format.html) says that one can mark a field as `IGNORE` in order to "Ignore this field completely".

I've created a header file with the following:

```
tx_id:ID,:IGNORE,value:int
```

and a content file as

```
1, some value to be ignored, 100

2, another value to be ignored, 200
```

but when using the Neo4J 2.2 import tool it failed again and again.
I tried many variants but without success.
Any idea how can i ignore a column/field from the imported CSV file?

I'm using version 2.2.0-M04
Using --stacktrace i got the following

Import error: 'IGNORE'
java.lang.RuntimeException: 'IGNORE'
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.StageExecution.stillExecuting(StageExecution.java:63)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.anyStillExecuting(ExecutionSupervisor.java:70)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.finishAwareSleep(ExecutionSupervisor.java:93)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.supervise(ExecutionSupervisor.java:55)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.executeStages(ParallelBatchImporter.java:267)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:151)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:216)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'IGNORE'
        at org.neo4j.csv.reader.Extractors.valueOf(Extractors.java:140)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.DataFactories$DefaultNodeFileHeaderParser.entry(DataFactories.jav
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.DataFactories$AbstractDefaultFileHeaderParser.create(DataFactorie
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.createNestedIterator(InputGroupsDeseriali
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.createNestedIterator(InputGroupsDeseriali
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.NestingIterator.fetchNextOrNull(NestingIterator.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.peek(PrefetchingIterator.java:60)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.IteratorBatcherStep.nextOrNull(IteratorBatcherStep.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep.process(ProducerStep.java:74)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep$1.run(ProducerStep.java:56)

Thanks

Comment: Which exact version did you use? Can you retry with 2.2.0-M04 ?

Comment: How did it fail? Can you run the tool with --stacktraces and share the output?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.0-M04    system\coordinator\lib

Comment: Hi. This will be fixed from RC1. See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4095

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that will be fix in RC1